# XMLHttpRequest Not Stopping

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, xmlhttprequest, angular6

I have an XHR to upload files. The user is able to click on a button to cancel the upload.

This then sets `file.canceled` to `true`. I am checking in the `onprogress` event whether the upload has been canceled.

If it was canceled, I call `xhr.DONE`. However, this doesn't stop the upload process at all.

**Code** (I am using Angular 6, so it's Typescript)

```
upload(f: ProductFile): Observable<ProductFile> {
    var file: ProductFile;
    this.store$.pipe(
        select(FilesSelectors.getFileById(f._id)),
    ).subscribe((file: ProductFile) => file = file)
    return new Observable((observer) => {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        let progress: number = 0;
        xhr.upload.onprogress = (event: ProgressEvent) => {
            if (event.lengthComputable) {
                progress = 100 * (event.loaded / event.total);
                this.store$.dispatch(new FilesActions.UploadProgress({
                    ...file, progress, uploaded: false, uploading: true,
                }));
            }
            if (file.canceled) {
                observer.error('canceled')
                observer.complete();
                xhr.DONE;
            }
        }
        xhr.responseType = 'json';
        xhr.open('POST', `${this.httpService.url}/files/upload`, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', this.httpService.token);
        xhr.send(f.formData);
        xhr.onload = () => {
            const finishedFile: ProductFile = {
                ...f,
                url: xhr.response,
                uploaded: true,
                uploading: false,
                progress: 100,
            };
            observer.next(finishedFile);
            observer.complete();
            xhr.DONE;
        }
    });
}
```

So my goal is the abort the uploading process when `file.canceled` equals `true`

Comment: I know people hate when comments suggest using a library, but when it comes to making ajax calls, i really think you should be using an abstraction of some sort. axios is pretty good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the abort()  method of the XMLHttpRequest object instead of DONE.

Like this:

```
xhr.abort();
```